# How to get tomorrow's date in NetLogo

Tags: function, netlogo

Is there any function that will automatically get tomorrow's date in NetLogo. I'm trying with time extension but without luck. Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Please provide the code you are using. I would have pointed you to the time extension and, from its documentation, the command would be `set tomorrow time:plus dt 1 "days"`